# Foundation fire event on modal popup

Tags: asp.net, modalpopup

I use a modal of foundation(http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/reveal.html)
now I have a button inside the modal and I want to fire event when user press on the button.
but the event don't fire..
someone can help me?!

Answer (score 0):

I find the soulation:
define LinkButton insead Button: